# Rails 3: Is there anything wrong with the syntax for my named scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there anything wrong with the syntax for my named scope?  Because it ain't workin...

```
scope :that_is_registered_in_tournament_with_username, lambda { |tourney_id, name| where("username = ? and tournament_id = ?", name, tourney_id).first }
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: What does "it ain't workin" mean?

Comment: Syntax looks good to me. Are you getting an error or is it just not returning anything? Can you see the query in the log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is first. First actually picks the first object from a given relation. Thus, it's actually an object and not a relation. I think that if you lose .first, it will work.